# how to show image in ScrollView when the user rotate the device to landscape without code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-storyboard

I'm learning Developing Apps for iOS (CS193P) in Stanford And I'm doing Assignment 4. There is the Required Task

> If the user touches on an image in your newly created view controller, segue to yet another new MVC which lets the user scroll around and zoom in on the image. When the image first appears in this new MVC, it should display zoomed (in its normal aspect ratio) to show as much of the image as possible but with no “whitespace” around it. The user can then scroll around and zoom from there.

But teacher give a Hint and I don't how to do it:

> A cool feature of your application is (should be!) that if the user wants to zoom in on a Tweet’s image a bit without clicking on it to segue to the detailed image viewing MVC, the user can simply rotate the device to landscape. If you implement things properly, you’ll get this feature “for free” (i.e. no code required).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make use of AutoLayout for this to work properly. Make sure your app supports both portrait and landscape orientations from the project settings. Then just add constraints for space from borders of your ImageView to the ScrollView. Make sure you put a >= constraint. Now when you turn your device to landscape, your scrollView width and height will increase, which in turn will expand your imageView, and zoom your image.

Comment: I understand your suggestion. But Sorry about I didn't explain the detail of assignment. There are a TableView and the ImageView is in the cell of this TableView. Required Task ask me to segue another MVC when user touch the TableViewCell. The new MVC only have a ScrollView in Storyboard and the ImageView is add by code. So I don't know how to do your suggestion in my assignment.